# Why would the parameter name matter with Web Api id works while memberId ( both int) does not work

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-web-api-routing

Just when after years of writing and consuming web api service methods,  I am doing a project in which I was calling from Angular and then when the breakpoint in web api was NOT hit I was using postman.

I ended up tracing it down to the simple name of the signatures incoming parameter

**This does NOT work**

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetActivityByMemberId(int memberId) {...}
```

**"id" WORKS , WHY ??**

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetActivityByMemberId(int id) {...}
```

**Postman & Angular call**

```
http://localhost:49810/umbraco/api/activityapi/GetActivityByMemberId/2
```

I'm a bit lost as to why I would have to change parameter name to "id" when I do not even specify that in Postman (testing)  or Angular `$http.get`  ...

Help me understand!  Please !

Comment: Show `WebApiConfig`. It looks like a routing parameter matching issue. Most probably you are using convention-based routing and the routeTemplate has something like `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`. It is match the parameter names in the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a routing parameter matching issue. Most probably you are using convention-based routing and the `routeTemplate` has something like

```
// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

It is matching the parameter names in the route template to those in the controller actions.

read up on [Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) to get a better understanding of how routing works

Comment: Oh my,   No wonder why previous jobs and projects I never had problems  .. I always used [Route..]  attributes !    That is why , right?

Comment: Attribute routing ie `[Route...]` allowed for more flexibility but followed a similar format where you would have matched the parameter names in the route to those of the action as well

Comment: FYI,  with a post with passing in JSON of a model of 'Activity'  this does work without a change to adding [Route] or editing routeTemplate in that file..

Comment: Thus [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateActivity(Activity activity)   works without doing anything

Comment: the post worked because the model binder looks at the properties of the parameter not the name itself. everything is explained in the linked article.

Comment: Thanks so much   Nkosi

Answer (score 2):

Struggled to explain the same situation from the default WebAPI configuration. Though this query is old, posting this just in case this alternative helps others!

The default route config in Web API is (there is no action, the action will be chosen based on the Http verb of the request):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And in this case the method signature expected will be with the variable name as "id" and no other names will be accepted if you want to invoke the method using path "../api/ControllerName/5678".

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetActivityByMemberId(int id) {...}
```

**However, a minor tweak will get the URI working for any variable name. Just change the signature of the method to**

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetActivityByMemberId([FromUri(Name = "id")] int memberId) {...}
```